# String of values separated by commas or semicolons into a Python list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm reading a list of email addresses from a config file. The addresses can be delimited by comma or semicolon - e.g.,

```
billg@microsoft.com,steve@apple.com, dhh@37signals.com
billg@microsoft.com;steve@apple.com;  dhh@37signals.com
```

I'd like to get rid of any whitespace around the email addresses too.

I need to get them into a Python list like this:

```
['billg@microsoft.com', 'steve@apple.com', 'dhh@37signals.com']
```

What's the most Pythonic way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case I whould use the re module

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> data = "billg@microsoft.com;steve@apple.com;  dhh@37signals.com"
>>> stuff = re.split(r"\s*[,;]\s*", data.strip())
```

Comment: And use data.strip() to get rid of leading whitespace before the first and trailing whitespace after the last.

Comment: woops, forgot that. .strip() added. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Regular expressions are powerful, and probably the way to go here; but for something as simple as this, string methods are OK too. Here's a terse solution:

```
[s.strip() for s in s1.replace(',', ';').split(';')]
```

Test output:

```
>>> s1 = "billg@microsoft.com,steve@apple.com, dhh@37signals.com"
>>> s2 = "  billg@microsoft.com;steve@apple.com;  dhh@37signals.com  "
>>> print [s.strip() for s in s1.replace(',', ';').split(';')]
['billg@microsoft.com', 'steve@apple.com', 'dhh@37signals.com']
>>> print [s.strip() for s in s2.replace(',', ';').split(';')]
['billg@microsoft.com', 'steve@apple.com', 'dhh@37signals.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's only ';' or only ',' and you know which, use string.split:

```
>>> 'adjifjdasf;jdiafjodafs;jdiajof'.split(';')
['adjifjdasf', 'jdiafjodafs', 'jdiajof']
```

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

**EDIT** For whitespace you can also do:

```
>>> map(str.strip, 'adjifjdasf;jdiafjodafs ; jdiajof'.split(';'))
['adjifjdasf', 'jdiafjodafs', 'jdiajof']
```

Comment: There's also the issue of whitespace.

Comment: you may have forgotten that Ambrosio wants to get rid of leading and trailing whitespaces...

Comment: Doesn't handle both cases (i.e. can be ',' or ';' delimited).

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.maketrans to replace multiple separators with spaces in a single pass

```
import string

data = "one  two,  three ; four "
stuff = [i for i in data.translate(string.maketrans(";,", "  ")).split()]

print stuff   # -> ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using just Python's string manipulation facilities:

```
import string

s1 = "billg@microsoft.com,steve@apple.com, dhh@37signals.com"
s2 = "billg@microsoft.com;steve@apple.com;  dhh@37signals.com"

print s1.translate(string.maketrans(';',','), string.whitespace).split(',')
# ['billg@microsoft.com', 'steve@apple.com', 'dhh@37signals.com']
print s2.translate(string.maketrans(';',','), string.whitespace).split(',')
# ['billg@microsoft.com', 'steve@apple.com', 'dhh@37signals.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = '''   billg@microsoft.com,steve@apple.com, dhh@37signals.com  
  billg@microsoft.com;steve@apple.com;\t  \rdhh@37signals.com       '''

print repr(data),'\n'

import re

print re.findall('[^,\s;]+', data)
```

result

```
'   billg@microsoft.com,steve@apple.com, dhh@37signals.com  \n  billg@microsoft.com;steve@apple.com;\t  \rdhh@37signals.com       ' 

['billg@microsoft.com', 'steve@apple.com', 'dhh@37signals.com', 'billg@microsoft.com', 'steve@apple.com', 'dhh@37signals.com']
```

notice the '\n' , '\t' and '\r' in this data

Answer (score -1):

```
def gen_list(file_path):
    read= open(file_path, "r")
    split1= read.split(";")
    new_list= []
    for i in split1:
       split2 = i.split(",")
       split_list = [item.strip() for item in split2 if "@" in item]
       new_list.extend(split_list)
       return new_list
```

#
This works for both comma and ;. The number of lines can further be reduced